# Unsupervised Clustering of Images: Which Algorithms?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, dimensionality-reduction

Given a set of images $ \left\{ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^{N} $ how could one cluster them in an unsupervised manner? What are the useful features / tools to do so?

For instance, will extracting the images mean and variance be a useful method?

**Update:**

Let's take an example!
I have MNIST database. It contains lots of images with the size 28x28.
I want to make a plot like this. What should I use to get all the x-axis points and y-axis points?

[image]

Comment: both mean and variance have  unambiguous definition. Could you elaborate on what is unclear about that?

Comment: “It's sounds too easy (and very wrong) to just use some few basic MATLAB commands for compute the mean and variance in an image.” Yes, it’s easy. That doesn’t make it wrong. The mean and standard deviation (MATLAB functions `mean` and `std`) are trivial statistics. They are also unlikely to be very helpful in distinguishing images.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have seen lots of scatter plots where each dot inside the scatter plot is an image. I wonder how they compute that dot that represent one single image. I assume it some kind of average/std, but I'm not sure. Think...image classification with scatter plots.

Comment: @MrYui we can't possibly guess what these scatter plots you've seen showed. Chances are you're wrong about it being mean and average. Anyway, no plot is useful without a complete legend / description what it shows. It makes no sense to speculate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have posted an example what I want to achieve.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is it covariance I'm seeking?

Comment: @MrYui that is t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding (t-SNE). Check [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/dimensionality-reduction-using-t-distributed-stochastic-neighbor-embedding-t-sne-on-the-mnist-9d36a3dd4521) and [this paper](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/JMLR_2008.pdf).

Comment: @MrYui you will have to read the document that contained this scatterplot. As you can see on its axes, it's neither variance, nor covariance, nor mean; it's t-SNE, and way more complicated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have read some more information. It seems that I'm seeking some kind of dimension reduction. One question. Each axis in e.g PCA, is that the covariance?

Comment: please don't jump topics in the comments. Open a new question post if you have a new question! Add a comprehensive description of what you have researched regarding your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, We're too easy on the `close` trigger. We can edit the question for clarity and make it a valid resource.

Comment: @Royi not to disagree too much, but the post-close edit completely changed the direction and content of the question. Before, it was literally just "how do I calculate mean and variance", then it became the overly broad "what's this figure and how can I make one"; even in its current form I'd say, "hey, that's a nice figure, I bet it came from some publication; did you have a chance to look into what t-SNE is? Maybe you have a question regarding that!".

Comment: @Royi I prefer to be easy on both the close and the reopen triggers. I prefer not to try to divine what the OP is really asking, though I'm OK with others trying. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsupervised clustering of image data is tricky thing and requires adjusting the method to the content of the images set.

Assuming we're dealing with the [MNIST data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) we can do some nice things using known tools.
First, let's assume we're after 2 features, namely we're after a dimensionality reduction from 784 features / dimensions to 2.

The first approach you suggested, using Mean and Variance isn't fruitful for images.
This can be shown form the following image:

[image]

As we can see, the mean and variance features doesn't create separation between different classes of the data.

The other algorithm in your question, the [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding), originally developed for visualization is very capable in tasks like this.
It can reduce the dimensionality while keeping the classes information:

[image]

The idea is finding a method to embed data which is similar in high dimension closely in low dimension and keep data which is not similar far away.
Indeed in the figure above one could see that in most cases same digits are grouped together.

After the t-SNE we saw few other similar dimensionality reduction algorithm which are as capable (Even more) like [UMAP](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426).

The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing Q80767 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q80767` folder).

Comment: Nice answer! Also good to see you sharing code on GitHub.

Comment: @PeterK., Thank you! I think it was you who made me do that. I saw it once on one of your answers, that you share the code on GitHub, and thought it is a great way to conserve knowledge. The best engineering is a copied engineering :-).

Comment: Very good! I like it! Is UMAP better than T-sne? Who is fastest? Who is easiest?

Comment: Can you show with LDA as well?

Comment: @Royi Yes! Here you go and thank you for your answer. Very helpful to see the difference between PCA and t-SNE. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/80949/whats-the-result-after-linear-dicriminant-analysis-compared-to-t-sne-umap