# Image Clustering Using Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) Compared to t-SNE / UMAP

Tags: image-processing, matlab, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, dimensionality-reduction

This is a a continuation of the discussion from [Unsupervised Clustering of Images](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/80767).

Image that we have MNIST database and we want to separate all the images like this. But we want to use [Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) (LDA) instead to see how the results differ.

**Question**

Will LDA perform better than t-SNE/UMAP if we know the classes of the data?
Let's say that the X and Y axis of the plot is covaraiance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Linear Discriminant Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) (LDA) (Also the Fisher's Linear Discriminant, which the LDA is a generalization of) is a method to find a projection plane to separate data by linear projection Matrix multiplication).
Its main limitation is the use of linear projection.
On the other hand, it can be used in a supervised manner. Namely it can use the labels to find the optimal projection.

I implemented LDA in MATLAB and compared to the t-SNE from [the previous question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/80767).

Supervised Dimensionality Reduction by LDA:

[image]

UnSupervised Dimensionality Reduction by t-SNE:

[image]

As one can see, though the LDA is supervised it can't compete with the t-SNE results. Though LDA could be very useful in other cases (Usually with fewer dimensions).
For instance, in order to validate my LDA implementation I used the [UCI Machine Learning Repository Wine Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine). I got the following result:

[image]

The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing Q80949 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q80949` folder).

### Resources

I found some resources about supervised dimensionality reduction:

- [Robust Linear Discriminant Analysis Using Ratio Minimization of $ {L}_{1, 2} $ Norms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00211).
- [Supervised Dimensionality Reduction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161362).
- [Supervised Linear Dimension Reduction Methods: Review, Extensions, and Comparisons](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.04244).
- [Supervised Dimensionality Reduction for Big Data](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-23102-2).
- [Linear Dimensionality Reduction: Survey, Insights and Generalizations](https://jmlr.org/papers/v16/cunningham15a.html).
- [SciKit Learn - Manifold Learning](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html).

Comment: I see. LDA perform much worst compared to t-SNE. If I would have data that I need to separate from e.g if I have 10 classes of data, then I create a linear projection matrix $X$ and when I multiply that $X$ matrix with a specific new unknown data class, then that data class will "move avay" from other data. I don't now how to explain, but in LDA, you can find a $W$ matrix that project the data (e.g a vector) to another plane. Assume that you have $x$ vector, but $X*x = y$ where $y$ is a new projection. Can t-SNE create a projection matrix as LDA can? Or is t-SNE only a optimization algorithm?

Comment: What you're after is transformation of new data. Unfortunately, `t-SNE` doesn't support it natively. You can do some things to approximate it but I'd not do it. Yet `UMAP` does support this and it is as powerful as t-SNE. So you can use it for that usage.

Comment: Ok. Yes, I think UMAP is the right thing because LDA is quite dizzy for me when I see the plots. It's like all scatters have melted togeher. But I don't want to re-compute UMAP for every new unknown data. Do you know UMAP? If you could extend your answer with UMAP?

Comment: By the way! I like your MATLAB code! Very easy to read.

Comment: There is no official UMAP for MATLAB. If you use Python it is easy. I try keeping my code clear and concise as sometime I need it down the road. The more verbose it is the easier for me to reuse it.

Comment: UMAP is probably very difficult to write too? I'm looking for a method were I can just multiply an image with an matrix 'W' and the image transform into another projection. LDA will work for that, but will UMAP generate a projection matrix 'W' or is UMAP an opimization method and don't generate a projection matrix 'W'?

Comment: Since UMAP isn't linear you can not represent it in a matrix form. For linear operators LDA probably is scratching the edge of what you can do.

Comment: Yes! LDA might be right for me. In your MATLAB code, do you use multiple features/components in LDA? I assume that LDA is a way to reduce higher dimension e.g 5 dimensions to e.g 2 dimensions?

Comment: Indeed. In the code above I used LDA to reduce features from 784 to 2!

Comment: One quick question. How can you find e.g multiple attributes/features/components from an image? I mean, if you compute the variance in an image, you get two axis values e.g x-variance and y-variance. That's covariance. But in this case, you reduce 3 dimension data to 2 dimension data. What's the third dimension of an image?

Comment: I'm asking a new question about that https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/80994/how-many-dimensions-can-i-find-inside-an-image